# Connected to MQ, but cannot disconnect, error 2018

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a difficulties with IBM MQ. I have connected to MQ, but couldn't disconnect. the message says:

```
2017-06-28|19:27:17|  133|Connection accepted, Channel [AVNCHCTM.CLIENT]  ConName [10.155.224.179] Flags [BlockMqmUsers=Y AllowBlankUserID=Y  UseridUpperLowerCase=* IQ    

NiL=0 ] User []
```

Could you please let me know how to disconnect now? I don't have valid connection handle Hconn . Error:

```
2018  MQRC_HCONN_ERROR
```

Can I force channel to stop and what could happen after that?
May be this situation has another solution?

I appreciate any possible help

Comment: `2018  MQRC_HCONN_ERROR` would indicate you are no longer connected and the connection handle is invalid.

Comment: But owner of MQ says that there is a connection. Are you trying to say that there is no connection established?

Comment: I get this error from MQDISC

Comment: So, no help? Look not at the error, but at the message from MQ server, please. It says connection accepted

Comment: That appears to be a log entry from BlockIP2.  The error you get indicates the handle is invalid.  In many cases this indicates the connection ended abnormally due to a network issue of some sort.  In your case based on your other recent SO post, maybe the Hconn you have is just not correct.  The Hconn gets returned from MQCONN/MQCONNX and when you call MQDISC you should be passing what was returned by MQCONN/MQCONNX.

Comment: Is there a firewall or other network device in between the client and the broker that could be killing connections based on a timeout?

Comment: `2018 MQRC_HCONN_ERROR` indicates that the variable you passed into MQDISC is not a valid hConn. This does not mean you are disconnected. In fact, should you become disconnected, you should always still call MQDISC to clean up storage used by MQ. Doing so will not result in this reason code. This reason code is likely to come about if you have made a coding error. Since you have not posted your MQCONN and MQDISC code we cannot tell you how to correct this. Please code you post your code.